# WinForms control to setup clickable areas in a UserControl

Tags: winforms, user-controls, label

Need to divide a UserControl with a background picture into multiple small clickable areas. Clicking them should simply raise an event, allowing to determine which particular area of the picture was clicked.

The obvious solution is using transparent labels. However, they are heavily flickering. So it looks like labels are not designed for this purpose, they take too much time to load.

So I'm thinking if any lighter option exists? To logically "slice up" the surface.

I also need a border around the areas, though.

Comment: You have to know when to stop using the designer and start writing some code.  This is such a case.  Simply override the OnMouseUp() method and calculate the "area" clicked from the e.Location property.  Draw borders by overriding OnPaint().

Answer (score 2):

on the user control do:

```
MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.UserControl1_MouseClick);
```

and now in the `UserControl1_MouseClick` event do:

```
  private void UserControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     int x = e.X;
     int y = e.Y;
  }
```

now let's divide the user control to a 10x10 area:

```
     int xIdx = x / (Width / 10);
     int yIdx = y / (Height / 10);

     ClickOnArea(xIdx, yIdx);
```

in `ClickOnArea` method you just need to decide what to do in each area. maybe using a 2d array of `Action`

as for the border do this:

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnPaint(e);

     Graphics g = e.Graphics;
     Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
     float xIdx = (float)(Width / 10.0);
     float yIdx = (float)(Height / 10.0);

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        float currVal = yIdx*i;
        g.DrawLine(p, 0, currVal, Width, currVal);
     }

     g.DrawLine(p, 0, Height - 1, Width, Height - 1);

     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
     {
        float currVal = xIdx * j;
        g.DrawLine(p, currVal, 0, currVal, Height);
     }

     g.DrawLine(p, Width - 1, 0, Width - 1, Height);
  }
```